# blackboard mathbold

Tags: math-mode, boldmath, blackboard

I have been using

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbmsl}{U}{bbm}{m}{sl}

$\mathbbmsl{H}$
```

to happily get

[image]

Is there a way to get its mathbold version? I tried

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbbsl}{U}{bbm}{b}{sl}

$\mathbbbsl{H}$
```

but only get

[image]

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: you want bold and blackboard bold and slanted all at the same time??

Comment: the fd file has `\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbm}{bx}{sl}` so you want bx not b for the bold version

Comment: @David, yes. I know it's a bit too much to ask for.

Comment: @David, Thanks very much. It works!!!!

Comment: note as your image shows these are only available as bitmap fonts so will appear pixelated in many viewers.

Comment: @David, Indeed. I do hope that there is a solution producing pictures with higher quality. If you happen to know one, can you please share with me?

Comment: there are lots of scalable fonts with double struck math alphabets but I do not know any with bold slanted, why do you need that, bold blackboard bold already seems a slightly strange thing.

Comment: @David, I know it's bit strange. A solution for slanted doublestroke math alphabets with higher quality would be great, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to David.

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbbsl}{U}{bbm}{bx}{sl}

$\mathbbbsl{H}$
```

does the trick:

[image]